# GitHub: authenticity of host can't be established ONLY for submodule update --init

Tags: git, github

Trying to run `git submodule update --init` for a repo I have cloned from GitHub results in: `The authenticity of host 'github.com (140.82.121.4)' can't be established.`. I can still clone repos or fetch updates as usual and I don't get this warning. What is going on here?

Answer (score 2):

Just adding github.com to known hosts should work.

```
ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Comment: Ok but I still don't get what is going on here. Why with these repos this is happening?