# git not recognizing the "yes" response

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to push to a GitHub repository for the first time, and I got the standard "authenticity of host can't be established" warning message. However, even when I respond "yes", it doesn't seem to be recognized:

```
PS D:\Code> git push --set-upstream origin master
The authenticity of host 'github.com (140.82.114.3)' can't be established.
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:(censored).
This key is not known by any other names.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Please type 'yes', 'no' or the fingerprint: yes
Please type 'yes', 'no' or the fingerprint: y
Please type 'yes', 'no' or the fingerprint: yes
Please type 'yes', 'no' or the fingerprint: yes
Please type 'yes', 'no' or the fingerprint: yes
Please type 'yes', 'no' or the fingerprint: yes
Please type 'yes', 'no' or the fingerprint: yes
Please type 'yes', 'no' or the fingerprint: yes
Please type 'yes', 'no' or the fingerprint: yes
Please type 'yes', 'no' or the fingerprint: yes
Please type 'yes', 'no' or the fingerprint:
```

Is there any way around this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66919702/7976758 `ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts` Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+The+authenticity+of+host+github.com+can%27t+be+established

Comment: FYI, there's no need to censor github.com's public key fingerprint. My [magic ball](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/githubs-ssh-key-fingerprints) tells me that `(censored)` is `+DiY3wvvV6TuJJhbpZisF/zLDA0zPMSvHdkr4UvCOqU` :)

Comment: Doing `ssh-keyscan` is insecure because all it tells you is what the key is now, which doesn't mean that's what it's supposed to be.  For example, if you're on a network that MITMs SSH, then that will give you the wrong key.  If you want GitHub's SSH keys in a programmatic way, [get them from the API](https://api.github.com/meta).

Answer (score -1):

I really hate to say this but, restarting my terminal has solved my issue